# Getting photos onto Android virtual device in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, testing, intellij-idea, upload, android-virtual-device

I'm working on an app to enable people to upload photos from their phone, and I need to be able to test this functionality out in the AVD via emulator. However the AVDs don't seem to have any photos in storage so I can't use them for testing.

Is there an efficient way to get photos onto the virtual device and preferably keep them there so I can run multiple tests on them? I know I can debug on my phone as well (and have been doing that), however I would prefer to do most of my debugging on the emulator if possible.

I'm using the IntelliJ IDEA for development.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to open cmd window and type adb shell. You can then create a folder for the images you'd like in the sdcard folder. Then you can exit the shell and push the images to the device using adb push cmd.

It's pretty simple actually.

```
adb shell
cd sdcard
md directoryName

exit

adb push /sdcard/directoryName /pathToImage
```

Comment: Thanks. Where would I do this in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by starting the Android Device Monitor in IntelliJ (Tools>Android>Android Device Monitor), navigating to the File Explorer tab, and copying pictures over to the sdcard>Downloads folder. In the device emulator, I selected 'show SD card' before I was able to use the pictures from that folder. It will probably be easier if I can find out how to put the pics on a device folder instead of SD card, but for now this suffices.

Thanks for the suggestion eclipse, helped me go down the right path.